# Complex method chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

For context, I'm thinking about [this type of method chaining](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate), in which the final method called returns a promise. My question is different from [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-chain-asynchronous-functions-in-javascript/), however.

I'm truly stumped with this, so bear with me on my lack of reproducible examples. I'm not even too sure where to begin with this. It's also not a homework question.

Consider the function `foo` on the class `Bar`, which takes in a few parameters. `foo` is asynchronous and returns a promise. `baz` is totally **optional**, and can be chained onto `foo` (`foo(param).baz(someOtherParam)`), which will affect the way `foo` is eventually run. What's important to note here is that `foo` will return without the chained `baz` being called, but if `baz` **IS** called, it will be the one who returns the promise (not `foo`).

My explanation is probably confusing, so here's a visual example:

```
// The promise is returned by the .where() 
const data = await User.where({ age: { $gte: 21 } })

// The .gte() function affects the execution. The promise is returned from .gte()
const data = await User.where('age').gte(21)

// .gte() doesn't return the promise anymore. The second chained .where() does.
// But also we can just continue chaining onto that pretty much endlessly if we want to.
const data = await User.where('age').gte(21).where('name', /^b/i)
```

I understand how to method chain with synchronous functions just fine - just return an object with some methods on it and you're pretty much good to go. What has me stumped is this implementation, which you can see a lot in libraries.

Comment: *which you can see a lot in libraries*, you should look at how they do it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I like your comment but I figured someone here could help me out. That's what this place is for yeah?

Comment: In the mongoose example you linked, the chain ends with a call to [an `exec()` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) which actually does the thing you've been chaining up to. I'm not sure your flow is possible without that.

Comment: @AlexWayne What about the code example I showed? That doesn't end in `exec()`

Comment: Well that's an API you made up, which I don't think makes a lot of sense. Show me an example of a chaining library that builds a query and does not intend to end that chain with a method that finalizes the query.

Comment: @AlexWayne That's not an API I made up. That is straight up Mongoose code straight from the Mongoose docs.

Comment: Apologies, you're right! https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-thenable shows what you mean. They recommend using the `exec` method, though. I have a theory. I will try to update this later.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks so much! btw oregon vibes I'm from the Willamette valley originally

Comment: The secret is that `foo()` doesn't actually return a promise. It returns an object with a `.then()` method, which is called by `await` (or any other feature that attempts to resolve the value into a promise), and will start the work only there. Apart from `then`, the object can have other normally chainable methods.

Comment: A possible simple solution that uses a cancelable promise that only resolves if the chain did not continue synchronously. https://tsplay.dev/WKq0zN. But that linked answer makes a lot more sense.